# How to send log to Datadog without Datadog agent

Tags: datadog

In my understand, usual case is using Datadog agent to send error to Datadog.
However, I'd like to know there are some ways to send error to Datagog without Datadog agent.

For example, can we send by using Datadog webhooks?

Answer (score 7):

You can use most any of the common open source log shippers to send server logs to Datadog without using the Datadog agent, for example [fluentd](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/fluentd/). But there can be several benefits to using the Datadog agent to collect server logs, such as:

- If you are using the Datadog agent for other monitoring data already, it saves you having to run/manage more software for log collection
- It's the safest way to make sure you get all the right tags applied to both your logs and other monitoring data (like metrics, traces, etc.) for better correlation of data when you're investigating stuff.

There are other ways to collect logs in Datadog, among those is the [HTTP API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/v1/logs/#get-a-list-of-logs). Since this API uses a POST method, I bet you could configure Datadog's [webhook integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/webhooks/) to generate log events from Datadog events and alerts. That said, before you go through the trouble of doing this, if you have a use-case or reason you're interested in doing this, you may want to reach out to Datadog support to see if they have some features coming / in beta that would get you what you want without the extra work on your end. (What *is* your use-case? I'm curious)

Comment: Thank you for the very useful information.
Please let me introduce you to my use case.

* Language: Golang
* Environment: GCP compute engine
* When a program running on Golang fails, logs are output on the same server.
I want to link that log with Datadog.
We already have a common Datadog, I want to be able to send logs to that Datadog and monitor the error log.